# PEAR: Could not open input file: Files

Tags: php, apache, file, input, pear

I've tried everything I know to solve this, but this error still occurs.

```
C:\windows\system32>pear install MDB2-2.5.0b5
Could not open input file: Files

C:\windows\system32>pear
Could not open input file: Files
```

Im using PHP 5.2.17 with Apache 2.2.

Everything seems fine with `php.ini` and `pear.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find the error, on the pear.bat that i executed on the final part where it shows `-d include_path=\".;%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%"`
i simply removed the `\` so the right one is:

```
-d include_path=".;%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%"
```